# Configure gradle build to suppress javadoc console warnings

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I'm configuring a gradle build using gradle's [javadoc plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html). I was able to stop the build from failing on account of javadoc lint errors, but there are still hundreds of lines of console output for those lint errors that I don't care about.

Any ideas how to suppress these console messages related to linting?

Example output that I'm talking about (but screens and screens full):

```
/home/user/projects/my-project/src/main/java/my/package/MyObject.java:89: warning: no description for @param
     * @param myParam
       ^
/home/user/projects/my-project/src/main/java/my/package/MyObject.java:90: warning: no description for @return
     * @return
       ^
/home/user/projects/my-project/src/main/java/my/package/MyObject.java:101: warning: no @param for itemId
    List<MyItem> getMyItems(Long itemId);
                        ^
```

I should clarify, I'm looking for a solution within the build configuration—not a flag to pass to the `gradle build` command every time I run it.

Comment: simply fix the javadoc annotations.

Comment: @MartinZeitler While heeding the lint warnings would take care of it, I don't think it's a best practice to do so. They expect documentation for every parameter, return value, etc. For some public projects this may be best, but for projects internal to my company I think the warnings encourage wasted effort and bloated documentation.

Comment: just remove the root cause and remove the incomplete javadoc completely instead of silencing the symptoms they cause.

Comment: @mrt181 while I agree that this is a good idea anyway, for the example in this particular question, the issue also happens when the javadoc is completely missing. For every single method and field. Even all the private ones.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warnings/errors can be suppressed using the Xdoclint option:

```
javadoc.options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
```

This will still show a few of the worst warnings, but will remove the vast majority of them.

See: https://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

As an aside, according to the gradle javadoc documentation you can set the output level directly (VERBOSE or QUIET). The problem is that QUIET still shows all warning and error messages and seems to be the default behavior anyway.

Comment: Any idea why `javadoc.options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none')` alone still shows the warnings?

Comment: @CaptainMan Nope. No idea.

Answer (score 9):

Doing this in a Kotlin build script is tricky. For some reason the `options` object is a `MinimalJavadocOptions` instead of `CoreJavadocOptions` meaning you don't get the `addStringOption` method. You can cast it though! Being a Kotlin novice it took me some time but this is what I have found:

```
plugins {
    java
}

tasks {
    javadoc {
        options {
            (this as CoreJavadocOptions).addStringOption("Xdoclint:none", "-quiet")
        }
    }
}
```