# Option Xdoclint:none does not work in Gradle to ignore JavaDoc warnings?

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I want to suppress Javadoc warnings in the output, because it fails the automatic builds.

```
task clientApiDocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    destinationDir = reporting.file("javadoc")
    classpath = configurations.compile
    options.addBooleanOption('Xdoclint:none', true)
}
```

This task will print some warnings:

```
User.java:124: warning - @param argument "password" is not a parameter name.
StateListener.java:17: warning - @author: is an unknown tag.
```

There are many of them, and It's not possible to fix them.

I tried to add `options.addBooleanOption('Xdoclint:none', true)` and `options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')` but this does not help. There are still Javadoc warnings in concole.

However, comparing to Ant, option `<javadoc destdir="${dir.build}/doc" additionalparam="-Xdoclint:none">` works pretty well and does not print any warnings.

It seems like there are many of people who tried to solve the same problem, but there is no way to deal with it. E.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205209/configure-gradle-build-to-suppress-javadoc-console-warnings)

What is the possible way or workaround to resolve it?

Comment: `-Xdoclint:none` does not suppress JavaDoc warnings, as you can see if you run the tool from the command line. I don't know of a way to actually do that, but you can at least reduce the number to a single printed warning with `options.addStringOption('Xmaxwarns', '1')`.

Comment: Thank you Bjørn Vester, I tried it, what a pity there is no such possibility to set 'Xmaxwarns' to '0'

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity that it cannot be switched off completely, the following 2 ways of reducing do get close though ... in build.gradle.kts, kotlin:

```
tasks.withType<Javadoc> {
    options {
        this as StandardJavadocDocletOptions
        addBooleanOption("Xdoclint:none", true)
        addStringOption("Xmaxwarns", "1")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Javadoc> {
    (options as StandardJavadocDocletOptions).addBooleanOption("Xdoclint:none", true) 
    (options as StandardJavadocDocletOptions).addStringOption("Xmaxwarns", "1")
}
```